# Как реализовать итерацию по списку типов ?

Tags: c#

Имеется обобщенный метод:

```
private void FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<T>(...)
```

он используется с различными типами

```
FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<Duct>(...);
FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<Pipe>(...);
FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<CableTray>...);
FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<Conduit>(...);
```

Как реализовать итерацию по списку типов (Duct etc.)? Думал что так, но оказалось неправильно:

```
foreach(Type type in typeList)
   FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<typeof(type)>(...);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сделать дополнительный метод `FillConnectorsListsWithEnds(Type targetType,...` то есть передать  не generic параметром, а обычным параметром метода.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите просто:

```
foreach (var type in typeList)
{
    if (type == typeof(Duct))
        FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<Duct>();
    else if (type == typeof(Pipe))
        FillConnectorsListsWithEnds<Pipe>();
    // etc
}
```